# Oracle Package return table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a table via a function in an Oracle package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test AS

    TYPE rec IS RECORD(
        col1 VARCHAR(10));

    TYPE rec_table IS TABLE OF rec;

    FUNCTION get_table(input VARCHAR2)
        RETURN rec_table
        PIPELINED;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test AS

    FUNCTION get_table(input VARCHAR2)
        RETURN rec_table
        PIPELINED IS

    rec1 rec;

BEGIN
SELECT * INTO rec1
FROM
(
SELECT '1' from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' from dual
);

PIPE ROW (rec1)
RETURN;
END get_table;
END;
```

but when I try to run

```
select * from table(test.get_table('blah'))
```

I get an error: exact fetch returns more then requested number of rows

I've read a bit about BULK COLLECT INTO, but I am not understanding the syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code:

```
SELECT '1' from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' from dual
```

Returns two, not one record, and you are trying to put those two records in one `rec` variable. You should instead loop through the results of the `UNION`:

```
FOR v_rec IN (
  SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT '1' from dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '2' from dual
    )
  )
LOOP
  PIPE ROW (v_rec);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: do I have to declare v_rec as something?

Comment: @mrkb80 No, should not - it is done automatically for you by Oracle.